# Parallel circuit and Ohms law

Tags: parallel, ohms-law

[image]

Theoretical questions with ideal components.(R2 is 10 Ohm)

1) parallel circuit. R1 and ammeter,

If I have a parallel circuit of 2 resistances, both zero Ohm, the current would split to 2 and each current would be half. If the resistor R1 would be 1 pico Ohm, and the ammeter zero Ohm, there would be no current through the resistor, and all the current would go through the ammeter?

2) Ohms law.

R2 is 10 Ohm, current is 1A.

voltage between point A and B is 0 volt,
resistance between A and B is 0 Ohm,

according to Ohms law, I = V / R = 0 / 0 = 0 A.

Correction, 0/0 is not 0, it is undefined.(edited after posting)

Is it telling me that it sees this as 2 circuits, with a common wire, and the circuit between A and B has no current, but the circuit between (+) and (-) has 1 Amp.

Correction, the current between A and B is undefined. (edited after posting)

Both questions are theoretical with ideal components, and the voltmeter and ammeter are connected this way on purpose. I would like to get some feedback on this topic.

Comment: There is one problem with your maths:  \$\frac{x}{0}=\infty\$.  (Actually "undefined", but infinity is the best approximation in this case).

Comment: 1: Yes, everything you said is correct. For #2, keep in mind that I can be anything (V = IR) if V and R are both zero; there are infinitely many solutions.

Comment: @Majenko, not when *x* is 0 also.

Comment: @ThePhoton Grab your favourite calculate and enter 0/0 and see what it says.

Comment: Majenko, I missed that. 0/0 is not a 0. Thank you.

Comment: @Majenko, \$\lim_{x\to{}0}{\frac{x}{0}}\$ is \$\infty\$. \$\lim_{x\to{}0}{\frac{0}{x}}\$ is 0. \$\lim_{x\to{}0}{\frac{3x}{x}}\$ is 3. Any of these would look like 0 / 0 if looked at naively.

Comment: @Majenko, Calculators do calculations, not math. And mine doesn't say 0/0 is infinity, it says "Error: undefined result" .

Comment: How would infinity divided by infinity compare to zero divided by zero?

Comment: Your circuit doesn't make sense. The voltmeter will tell you absolutely nothing and the ammeter will nullify R1, so effectively you'll be applying 10Vdc across R2 and you'll measure its current with the ammeter. Also, "the circuit between A and B has no current" - no, it's just that the voltmeter is not positioned to be able to see that current.

Comment: @sparkyAl, infinity is not a number. Usually it's a limit. "Infinity divided by infinity" depends what the two infinities are the limit of.

Comment: @ThePhoton Exactly. You have only read half of my initial statement. Read the entire statement, *including the bit in brackets*.

Comment: @Majenko, Except that infinity is **not** the best approximation in this case. 1 A is.

Comment: @ThePhoton 1A is the best approximation taking into account the rest of the circuit. That one portion, as an atomic unit by itself, the best approximation is \$\infty\$.

Comment: @ThePhoton That's your prerogative. It's a free world. The important fact is that \$\frac{x}{0} != 0\$. It *can* be 0, but it isn't always true that it *is* 0. The exact *limit* of the value it *could* be is neither here nor there, since the circuit in question is complete crap anyway. Everything else is just semantics: *"It all depends on what you mean by..."*.

Comment: @Majenko, I disagree. It all depends on what you mean (what limit you're taking) when you say V is 0 and R is 0. You could be talking about taking R to zero with constant V, or taking V to zero with constant R, or something else entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I have a parallel circuit of 2 resistances, both zero Ohm, the current would split to 2 and each current would be half.

"Zero ohms" is an idealization. If you say you have two zero-ohm resistors in parallel, it just means your model is not accurate enough to determine how the current is split.

> If the resistor R1 would be 1 pico Ohm, and the ammeter zero Ohm, there would be no current through the resistor, and all the current would go through the ammeter?

If "zero ohms" means much much less than 1 picoohm, then yes, essentially all the current would go through the ammeter.

But real ammeters have burden resistance that's much much more than a picoohm (more like a few milliohms).

> 2) Ohms law.
>   R2 is 10 Ohm, current is 1A.
>   voltage between point A and B is 0 volt, resistance between A and B is 0 Ohm,
>   according to Ohms law, I = V / R = 0 / 0 = 0 A.

You have a false conclusion. Zero divided by zero is not zero. It is an undetermined value. Could be zero or could be infinite, depending on the situation.

To analyze this circuit, restate Ohm's law as V = I R. You know the current is 1 A due to the other circuit elements. You know the voltmeter doesn't pass current. Therefore there's 1 A passing from B to A, and because it's a perfect wire, the voltage is zero.

Comment: The Photon, In 2 parallel branches with equal resistance, the current splits to 2 halves, also then if they have both 0 Ohm. But If instead of zero ohm, I would use infinitely small, then the split can't be determined. If one branch would have 0 Ohm, and the other infinitely small resistance, the branch with 0 Ohm resistance would conduct all the current and the branch with infinitely small resistance would not have any current. Am I correct on this?

Comment: @sparkyAl, there's no such thing as a perfect "zero ohm resistor" (except maybe a superconductor). So if you say your model contains two parallel zero-ohm resistors, then it means your model is not accurate enough to predict the current split for any real world situation.

Comment: When we model something as a zero-ohm resistor, we really mean "much smaller than any other resistance it's combined with". You can't have R(A) << R(B) and R(B) << R(A) at the same time.